# Flatlist Items flicker and then disappear

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

I have a Flatlist that is supposed to represent items.
Yesterday the Flatlist worked without problems, and today it started flashing heavily when rendering and when the screen is called up again, only the last item is displayed.
The data is pulled async in this screen via axios from an API

I then rebuilt the Flatlist to the minimum status, but the error remains.

```
<FlatList
            data={packages}
            horizontal
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            snapToInterval={packageCardWidth}
            bounces={false}
            decelerationRate={0}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
                return (
                    <PackageCard
                        containerWidth={packageCardWidth}
                        {...item}
                    />
                );
            }}
        />
```

The code for the rendered item

```
export default function PackageCard(props) {

return (
    <View style={[tw.style('flex-1'), { width: props.containerWidth }]}>
        <View
            style={[
                tw.style(
                    'bg-white rounded-lg shadow-md pb-4 m-3 overflow-hidden'
                ),
                {},
            ]}
        >
            <Image
                source={{
                    uri: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577705998148-6da4f3963bc8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=987&q=80',
                }}
                style={tw.style('h-64 w-full mb-4')}
            />
            <View style={tw.style('px-3 p-2')}>
                <Text style={tw.style('text-xl font-semibold')}>
                    {props.name}
                </Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    </View>
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There is several reasons for this, but in my case I just added this prop to the FlatList `initialNumToRender` and I gave it *the length of the whole data* which is I believe that this prop should be used to reduce the initial number of data for performance improvement, but I couldn't find any another way, to fix the problem other than this solution and it just works fine for me.

Example of the solution:

```
  <FlatList
     data={myData}
     initialNumToRender={myData.length}//
    />
```